# How can I exactly know what finish() does relate to setResult() in android?

Tags: android

When I called Activity B from Activity A, I just clicked back button and data is always null.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == NAME_REQUEST) {
        String name = data.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_NAME);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

That's because I didn't `setResult(...)` before `finish()`.

I tried to find a reason why I have to call it first, but I couldn't find it. I just found `super.onBackPressed()` follow by `finish()` like following code.

```
public void finishAfterTransition() {
    if (!mActivityTransitionState.startExitBackTransition(this)) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

And I found the following code, but I couldn't fully understand what happened when `finish()` called.

```
public void prepareToLeaveProcess(boolean leavingPackage) {
    ...
}
```

How can I know it? Is there any good way of trying it?

---

update

Ofs, I called setResult() but I tested like following code.

```
Button sendResultBtn = findViewById(R.id.button_send_result);
    sendResultBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /** solution 1 **/
            //sendResult();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /** solution 2 **/
    sendResult();
    super.onBackPressed();
    //sendResult();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    /** solution 3 **/
    //sendResult();
    super.finish();
    //sendResult();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //sendResult();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //sendResult();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //sendResult();
}

private void sendResult() {
    //Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));
    Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION");
    result.setType("text/plain");
    result.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, "Something");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    //finish();
}
```

I have to call setResult before finish() and I wanna know the reason.
Anyone who know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a result, you have to call setResult.  Otherwise how would the Activity know what to return.  Generally you don't call it right before calling finish-  you call it whenever a value is generated.  Then calling finish will automatically return the last value set.

For example-  if I have an image picker activity, every time an image was clicked I'd set the result (or I'd set it once at the start and update its values each click).  Then when finish was called normally, it would know what result to return.

As for what finish does-  it ends and Activity, and returns you to the previous one.

Comment: Even if I called setResult, I got null in onActivityResult 'cause I didn't call setResult before finish().

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L5630) for the `finish()` method.

The result of an Activity is an Intent. Inside of `finish()`, that Intent is passed to the ActivityManager, which then delivers it to the Activity that called `startActivityForResult()`.

If you don't call `setResult()`, that result Intent (the data), is null, because it was never set. Once you call `finish()`, whatever the the result data Intent is is what's sent to the ActivityManager.

Comment: I see, but I can't see inside of resultData.prepareToLeaveProcess(this) and ActivityManager.getService()
                        .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData, finishTask).
There is way for me to check this codes?

Comment: @libliboom here's the source code for Intent: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java